# Visual Basic, reading XML multi level nodes, and common attributes

Tags: xml, vb.net, nodes, element

I have an XML data file which changes every month.

It contains data from jobs printed, by a high end print system.  I need read the coverage data for each page, I can retrieve the job name and most of the data, but I can't seem to work out how to ready the individual coverage for each page (linking it to the specific page) ?

Example File:

```
<JOBS01_2016> 
  <JOB_01_06_2016_16_48_17> 
    <JOB> 
      <TICKETID>101</TICKETID>  
      <JOBNAME>A4 booklet and creep test file.pdf</JOBNAME>  
      <ERRORMESSAGE>Job processing was cancelled</ERRORMESSAGE> 
    </JOB> 
  </JOB_01_06_2016_16_48_17>  
  <JOB_01_09_2016_20_48_39> 
    <JOB> 
      <TICKETID>103</TICKETID>  
      <JOBNAME>BlackA45percol.pdf</JOBNAME>  
      <HEIGHT>6916</HEIGHT>  
      <WIDTH>9721</WIDTH> 
    </JOB>  
    <MEDIA> 
      <MEDIAHEIGHT>7016</MEDIAHEIGHT>  
      <MEDIAWIDTH>9921</MEDIAWIDTH>  
      <MEDIANAME>Intec Light</MEDIANAME>  
      <NUMBEROFPAGES>4</NUMBEROFPAGES> 
    </MEDIA>  
    <QUALITY> 
      <RESOLUTIONX>1200</RESOLUTIONX>  
      <RESOLUTIONY>600</RESOLUTIONY>  
      <COLORMODE>4</COLORMODE>  
      <COLORMODENAME>CMYK</COLORMODENAME> 
    </QUALITY>  
    <COVERAGE> 
      <PAGE> 
        <PAGENUMBER>1</PAGENUMBER>  
        <C>3483675</C>  
        <M>3483675</M>  
        <Y>3948165</Y>  
        <K>3483675</K> 
      </PAGE>  
      <PAGE> 
        <PAGENUMBER>2</PAGENUMBER>  
        <C>0</C>  
        <M>3483675</M>  
        <Y>3948165</Y>  
        <K>3483675</K> 
      </PAGE>  
      <PAGE> 
        <PAGENUMBER>3</PAGENUMBER>  
        <C>3483675</C>  
        <M>3483675</M>  
        <Y>464490</Y>  
        <K>3483675</K> 
      </PAGE>  
      <PAGE> 
        <PAGENUMBER>4</PAGENUMBER>  
        <C>3483675</C>  
        <M>3483675</M>  
        <Y>3948165</Y>  
        <K>0</K> 
      </PAGE> 
    </COVERAGE> 
  </JOB_01_09_2016_20_48_39> 
</JOBS01_2016>
```

I have written code to bring in the job names (Parent Nodes)?

```
     Dim xml As New XmlDocument
    xml.Load("Jobs_01_2016.xml")

    ListBox1().Items.Clear()

    For Each node As XmlNode In xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(node.Name)
    Next
```

Then the user selects the job name, and should get the Job Name, Job Height, Width, Resolution and number of pages, along with coverage for each page (linked to page number).
This I can't seem to get?
I can't work out how to read it in connection with the selected job, and specific page number?

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Fred As String
    Dim sbReadXML As New StringBuilder

    Fred = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim xml As New XmlDocument
    xml.Load("Jobs_01_2016.xml")

    Dim Jobname As String

    Jobname = xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/JOB/JOBNAME").InnerText
    sbReadXML.Append("Job Name: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(Jobname)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()

    Dim MediaHeight As Integer = Integer.Parse(xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/MEDIA/MEDIAHEIGHT").InnerText)
    sbReadXML.Append("Media Height: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(MediaHeight)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()
    Dim MediaWidth As Integer = Integer.Parse(xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/MEDIA/MEDIAWIDTH").InnerText)
    sbReadXML.Append("Media Width: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(MediaWidth)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()
    Dim Nopages As Integer = Integer.Parse(xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/MEDIA/NUMBEROFPAGES").InnerText)
    sbReadXML.Append("No of Pages: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(Nopages)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()
    Dim Printtime As String
    Printtime = xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/PRINT/PRINTTIME").InnerText
    sbReadXML.Append("Print Time: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(Printtime)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()
    Dim Resolutionx As Integer = Integer.Parse(xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/QUALITY/RESOLUTIONX").InnerText)
    sbReadXML.Append("Horizontal Resolution: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(Resolutionx)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()
    Dim Resolutiony As Integer = Integer.Parse(xml.SelectSingleNode("/JOBS01_2016/" + Fred + "/QUALITY/RESOLUTIONY").InnerText)
    sbReadXML.Append("Vertical Resolution: ")
    sbReadXML.Append(Resolutiony)
    sbReadXML.AppendLine()

    sbReadXML.Append(": ")

    txtContent.Text = sbReadXML.ToString 'Show Contents
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, can you specify/tag which Visual Basic (VB.Net, VBScript, VBA, etc.)? Second, you look to be transforming the XML by re-arranging data? Please post your desired result.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 - Visual Basic -  I am not trying (intending to Transform the data). The requirement, is a job costing tool, the RIP device outputs this XML containing the print job name of job, various data, along with the pixels used for the size of the job the resolution & the pixels used for each color plane.      I need to create a little interface, to read the xml, display jobs & allow the user to select each job, & as a result display the job cost.

Comment: For this, I need to be able to isolate each jobs' coverage, unique to each page, & each colorant.   I can't seem to get past childnodes.

Comment: I can read the parent nodes.  I can get the number of child nodes, I can't selectively point at a specific job Node, then the child node, then the coverage, then the  sub element for the specific page.   It is like the data has too many child of child node.?

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"

    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim jobs = doc.Elements().Select(Function(s) New With {
                                             .name = s.Name.LocalName,
                                             .jobs = s.Elements().Select(Function(t) New With {
                                                                             .jobName = t.Name.LocalName,
                                                                             .job = New With {
                                                                                 .ticketID = CType(t.Element("JOB").Element("TICKETID"), Integer),
                                                                                 .jobname = CType(t.Element("JOB").Element("JOBNAME"), String),
                                                                                 .height = CType(t.Element("JOB").Element("HEIGHT"), String),
                                                                                 .width = CType(t.Element("JOB").Element("WIDTH"), String),
                                                                                 .errorMsg = CType(t.Element("JOB").Element("ERRORMESSAGE"), String)
                                                                             },
                                                                            .media = t.Elements().Where(Function(u) u.Name.LocalName = "MEDIA").Select(Function(v) New With {
                                                                                 .height = CType(v.Element("MEDIAHEIGHT"), Integer),
                                                                                 .width = CType(v.Element("MEDIAWIDTH"), Integer),
                                                                                 .name = CType(v.Element("MEDIANAME"), String),
                                                                                 .pages = CType(v.Element("NUMBEROFPAGES"), Integer)
                                                                             }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                                            .quality = t.Elements().Where(Function(u) u.Name.LocalName = "QUALITY").Select(Function(v) New With {
                                                                                 .x = CType(v.Element("RESOLUTIONX"), Integer),
                                                                                 .y = CType(v.Element("RESOLUTIONY"), Integer),
                                                                                 .mode = CType(v.Element("COLORMODE"), Integer),
                                                                                 .name = CType(v.Element("COLORMODENAME"), String)
                                                                             }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                                            .coverage = t.Elements().Where(Function(u) u.Name.LocalName = "COVERAGE").Select(Function(v) New With {
                                                                                 .pages = v.Elements("PAGE").Select(Function(w) New With {
                                                                                    .pageNumber = CType(w.Element("PAGENUMBER"), Integer),
                                                                                    .c = CType(w.Element("C"), Integer),
                                                                                    .m = CType(w.Element("M"), Integer),
                                                                                    .y = CType(w.Element("Y"), Integer),
                                                                                    .k = CType(w.Element("K"), Integer)
                                                                                }).ToList()
                                                                             }).FirstOrDefault()
                                                                        }).ToList()
                                         }).FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub

End Module
​
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng, but this looks to be C+ ?  Any ideas for VisualStudio2013, visual Basic?   Or it may look like I have to learn C:-)

Comment: The code is VB.Net.  Make sure you add the two import statements at top of code.  Fully tested.   C# and VB.NET use same Net Library and code can easily be translated from one language to the other.